# How to create and register in SAP environment IDocListener?

Tags: java, sapjco3

We need implement SAP client on java to listen `IDoc`s.
We use

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <com.sap.conn.idoc.version>3.1.3</com.sap.conn.idoc.version>
        <com.sap.conn.jco.version>3.1.7</com.sap.conn.jco.version>
        <lib.directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</lib.directory>
    </properties>
...

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.conn.idoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.sap.conn.idoc.sapidoc3</artifactId>
            <version>${com.sap.conn.idoc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.sap.conn.jco.sapjco3</artifactId>
            <version>${com.sap.conn.jco.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
            <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
            <version>${com.sap.conn.jco.version}</version>
            <classifier>external-library</classifier>
            <type>dll</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
            <artifactId>libsapjco3</artifactId>
            <version>${com.sap.conn.jco.version}</version>
            <classifier>external-library</classifier>
            <type>so</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

the client configuration:

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, host);
        properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR, systemNumber);
        properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, client);
        properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER, username);
        properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, password);
        properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG, language);

        properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_GWHOST, host);
        properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_GWSERV, gatewayService);
        properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_GROUP, group);

        properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PEAK_LIMIT, peakLimit);
```

Using remind propertied we create `DestinationDataProvider` registering one in Environment `Environment.registerDestinationDataProvider(destinationDataProvider)`

then we can create `JCoDestination`, `JCoRepository` or `IDocRepository` without issues.

```
JCoDestination jCoDestination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("MULE_IDOC_TEST");
JCoRepository jCoRepository = jCoDestination.getRepository();
IDocRepository iDocRepository = JCoIDoc.getIDocRepository(jCoDestination);
```

Finally I need IDoc listener. I described class for one:

```
import com.sap.conn.idoc.IDocDocument;
import com.sap.conn.idoc.IDocDocumentIterator;
import com.sap.conn.idoc.IDocDocumentList;
import com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.JCoIDocHandler;
import com.sap.conn.jco.server.JCoServerContext;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;


@Slf4j(topic = "JCo IDoc Listener Logger")
public class JCoIDocListener implements JCoIDocHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(JCoServerContext jCoServerContext, IDocDocumentList iDocDocumentList) {
        log.info("idocs something");
        IDocDocumentIterator iterator = iDocDocumentList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            IDocDocument idoc = iterator.next();
            log.info("idoc : {}", idoc.toString());
        }
        log.info("server: {}", jCoServerContext.getServer());
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to register it in SAP client `Environment`.

### Question 1

Can you please help me to register object based on `JCoIDocListener` in SAP client `Environment`?

### Other way.

I described one more listener like:

```
import com.sap.conn.idoc.jco.JCoIDoc;
import com.sap.conn.jco.AbapClassException;
import com.sap.conn.jco.AbapException;
import com.sap.conn.jco.JCoFunction;
import com.sap.conn.jco.server.JCoServerContext;
import com.sap.conn.jco.server.JCoServerFunctionHandler;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j(topic = "JCo IDoc Server Listener Logger")
public class JCoIDocServerListener implements JCoServerFunctionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(JCoServerContext jCoServerContext, JCoFunction jCoFunction)
            throws AbapException, AbapClassException {
        log.info("received something");

    }
}
```

But the issue is also I have no idea how to register it in environment (beside that, it looks like server part).

### Question 2

Should I change my configuration for client `DestinationDataProvider` for using `JCoIDocServerListener`? If yes, how? (i think some server properties should be specified)
How to register `JCoIDocServerListener.class`?

Answer (score 0):

These properties are superfluous in your DestinationDataProvider client configuration:

```
properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_GWHOST, host); 
properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_GWSERV, gatewayService); 
properties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_GROUP, group);
```

And yes, your JCoIDocListener class implements RFC server functionality for receiving IDocs. For registering an RFC server, you have to implement and register a ServerDataProvider using the same pattern as with your implementation for the DestinationDataProvider.

Then you can call JCoIDoc.getServer(String name) for getting your JCoIDocServer instance. Finally, this instance must be started by calling JCoIDocServer.start(), but only after setting your JCoIDocHandler and a TIDHandler for it.

I recommend to have a look into the SAP Java IDoc Library's small example program IDocServerExample.java which is shipped with the SDK.

Comment: i checked the `IDocServerExample.java` before posting my question, but it didn't work for me :(

Comment: Generally, the example program works. But it doesn't use an own DestinationDataProvider or ServerDataProvider, but only the (unsecure) default implementations for both, which rely on property files for reading the connection parameters. Your posted code does not deal or start a JCoIDocServer - of course, this cannot work, if you want to listen/receive IDocs.